# loop index in R not increasing by 1

Tags: r, loops

This is a rather simple question: why is this code in R not printing numbers from 1 to 100, but jumps with the value of i? Is there a way to prevent this?

```
t <-5
for (i in 1:t){
    print(20*(i-1)+1:20*i)
}
```

Comment: what is the `*i` doing at the end of the `print` command? Just delete that and you will get the requested result

Comment: @Tom That does it, thank you. I think I had not understood the logic of the length of the sequence in R.

Answer (score 0):

to get the question closed

```
t <-5
for (i in 1:t){
    print(20*(i-1)+1:20)
}
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
#>  [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
#>  [1] 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
#>  [1] 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84
#>  [1] 85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```